# Rails why use capistrano when you have git post-receive hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I'm not familiar with Capistrano at all, I've just read some basic posts about configuring it. But my question is why bother with Capistrano if you can deploy your Rails application files using a git post-receive hook?

What does Capistrano offer that the hook doesn't?

I was looking into automated ways of deploying my Rails apps without using FTP and came across both git hooks and Capistrano.

Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git hooks allow you to execute script related to the git repository on a given action.

Capistrano allows you to administer your production deploys.

A single call to 'cap deploy' will clone your master branch on your target machine, archive the previous release, precompile your assets, restart passenger. Capistrano can also migrate your database, or execute any number of arbitrary commands you want on any server configured in your deploy.rb file.

Go with Capistrano for deploying to app/db server environments, you will have no trouble finding help when you get a problem with a deploy.

Comment: Thanks, so basically Capistrano gives you some more options like precompile and restart passenger. I see that it also allows you to keep versions of your app, that's pretty cool. More questions: It seems you have to deploy with the gems in your vendor folder for Capistrano to work. Is there a workaround for it to run bundle install after deploying?

Comment: No, you will install gems in the same way as in development, add to gemfile, then capistrano will autorun bundle install in production. It's really cool, you get prompted for your password when its necessary and you see the entire deploy scroll up the terminal.

Comment: Capistrano will also rollback the deploy to the last release if it encounters a problem. So you will not be left will a broken half installed app.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm currently fighting Capistrano to see if I can get it to do what I need :)